# What's the correct MAAS DHCP configuration?

Tags: configuration, maas, dhcp

I've set up a MAAS controller by following this documentation:
http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.4/cluster-configuration.html

However, when I got to the DHCP configurations I was a little puzzled.  The controller I created is at 172.16.142.61.  It looks like that's the address for the "IP" text field.  Going down the rest of the list I'm unsure of though.  Should I just put in the subnet/broadcast/router (is that the gateway?) that the MAAS server resides in or am I suppost to just list the static address of the MAAS server and then define my own "virtual" subnet in the fields below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DHCP configuration is for the MAAS server to be managing it's own subnet; this is how you would usually have a MAAS region/controller set up. The fields are as follows:

- **IP**: This is the IP address of your MAAS controller; you are correct
  in assuming that it would be 172.16.142.61 if you installed it at
  this address.
- **Subnet Mask**: This is the subnet mask of the MAAS region. Normally, you would put up a MAAS controller in its own subnet; the mask for that subnet goes here.
- **Broadcast IP**: This is the broadcast IP address of the subnet; it's usually something along the lines of an address ending in 255
- **Router IP**: This is the IP address of the router for your subnet as part of your MAAS region - i.e. your gateway. Type in the IP address for your connection to the larger internet here.
- **IP Range Low**: this is the start address for where a MAAS controller will begin handing out IP addresses to other clients. If you start the low range at, say, 100, then you can guarantee that machines on the network that request addresses will get an address which is at least 100.
- **IP Range High**: This is the end address for the MAAS controller's DHCP services - like the low value, this is instead the maximum IP address that will be allocated out to other machines by the DHCP.